# strace on phantomjs, why there isn't call to connect

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I am trying to run phantomjs on the following simple script (called te.js) and used "strace" on ubuntu 12.04 on it:

```
$ strace -o tmp.txt -e poll,select,connect,recv,sendto,recvfrom ./bin/phantomjs --disk-cache false te.js
```

The following is the javascript script:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var system = require('system');

page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
    system.stderr.writeLine('console: ' + msg);
};

page.open('http://st.pimg.net/tucs/img/cpan_banner.png', function() {
    console.log("got image\n");
});
```

Here is what the strace wrote to the tmp.txt

```
poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}], 1, 10)    = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
select(4, [3], [], [], {0, 0})          = 1 (in [3], left {0, 0})
select(4, [3], [], [], {0, 0})          = 1 (in [3], left {0, 0})
select(4, [3], [], [], NULL)            = 1 (in [3])
select(4, [3], [], [], {0, 0})          = 1 (in [3], left {0, 0})
select(4, [3], [], [], NULL)            = ? ERESTARTNOHAND (To be restarted)
--- SIGINT (Interrupt) @ 0 (0) ---
+++ killed by SIGINT +++
```

I had expected to see a call to "connect" but I don't.  Wonder why.

By the way, I used wireshark and it showed that phantomjs did try to set up connection to the HTTP server.

Comment: Which PhantomJS version is this? Did you compile Phantom on your own (or: where did you got it from)? Which hardware and OS 64 bit/32 bit? Could you please `strace` without limiting the calls to the above list (and added as gist/pastebin to your post)?

Comment: The PhantomJS version is 1.10.0 (development), I got the source and compiled it on my PC (64bit). Running strace without limit produce a lot of content, too long to attach here.  Thanks.

Comment: I said attach it as pastebin/gist (link to it). 1.10.0 isn't released yet, that's what you probably meant with "(development)". I suspect this error happens before the `connect` you're expecting and is probably rather related to thread execution, but not sure. I suggest you to mail to the PhantomJS mailinglist.

Comment: Thanks @try-catch-finally for the point, I will try other versions.